# Getting '500 - Internal server error' while running an Azure project

Tags: asp.net, azure

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

I have also added my IP to the firewall rule. I am a beginner in Azure.
I am getting the above error while trying to run the azure web project. I have added following tags after going through some articles but none help me.

```
 <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
 <identity impersonate="false"/>
```

Comment: Just to make sure, can you verify that the start up project is the Cloud project and not the web one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, your application is throwing an unhandled error.  You will want to know what the real error is, as Error 500 is just a generic way of saying: something happened.

You can deploy your app with customerrors being OFF so you can actually see the real error (Check this link for sample instructions: http://www.serverintellect.com/support/programming/custom-errors.aspx ).

Alternatively, if you're using WebRoles, you can RDP into a server instance and check Windows EventViewer, the details of the error will likely show up there.

Comment: I followed the latter. RDP and then open up IIS manager. There will be a link to "Browse <ip address>" on the right pane. The app page will open up on IE .Browse to the error page and you will see more details for the error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using code downloaded from durandaljs.com.  The "Build Action" on my default page (index.html) was set to "None", so this file was not uploaded to Azure during publish. Fixed by changing the "Build Action" to "Content".

Troubleshooting IIS via Remote Desktop really helped me figure this out.  Choosing the "Enable Remote Desktop for all roles" when you publish, then in Server Explorer, expand Cloud Services, etc., then right-click your instance and choose "Connect using Remote Desktop".

Answer (score 0):

This may be a proxy related issue.

Try adding these to your *.config files:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" />
</system.net>
```